# $(document).ready() firing before partial view is loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that has a partial view withing it.

**MyMainView.cshtml**

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("MyPartial")    
</div>
@section pagespecific {
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('Value is: ' + $('#MyModelField').val());
        });
    </script>
}
```

**MyPartial.cshtml**

```
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyModelField)
</div>
```

The value of `MyModelField` in the model is `True`, however, I get the following output into the browser console:

```
Value is: undefined
```

Why isn't this picking up the field? Shouldn't the partial view have been added to the DOM before this fires?

If I change the `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).load()` it works as expected.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: The DOM ready event cannot possibly fire before the server finishes constructing and sending the HTML markup to the browser.

Comment: I recommend viewing the source of page first before jumping to conclusion that `$('#MyModelField')` doesn't exist...

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is true, the reason is whenever your dom is ready `.ready` is fired. So your page is loaded first and it fires the jquery `.ready` function() , while the sequentially execution partial view also execute at server side.

Both are different in the usability.

To stop or you want to execute after some time.

- Either you can do this in partial view

or

- Give the delay time of your duration

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log('Value is: ' + $('#MyModelField').val());
      setTimeout("$('#buttonid').click()", DelayDuration);
  });
  ```

  //DelayDuration means give milisecond value, 1000 milisecond = 1 sec

The same question asked here

[JQuery events don't work with ASP.NET MVC Partial Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195168/jquery-events-dont-work-with-asp-net-mvc-partial-views)

[Is it possible to kick off a javascript function after a partial view renders in MVC Asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470046/is-it-possible-to-kick-off-a-javascript-function-after-a-partial-view-renders-in)

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready` doesn't fire before partial is rendered because partial view is rendered on server-side. You're using wrong ID in jquery because `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyModelField)` won't create element with ID="MyModelField". Element will have ID with prefix which is dependent on you model class name.

Inspect element's id in browser tools (F12) and determine the real ID.

Example:
If you model name is `User` class. The generated id will look like `User_MyModelField`

Comment: No - the ID is `MyModelField` in this case. This is from the page source: `<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The MyModelFieldfield is required." id="MyModelField" name="MyModelField" type="hidden" value="True">`